# Call the wordpress logout interface with a cookie, but the front end is not logged out

Tags: wordpress, rest, resttemplate

I tried to use RestTemplate to carry cookies and request a custom Wordpress logout interface, but the front end did not log out. When I directly accessed the logout url in the browser, I was able to logout successfully.
Here is my RestTemplate code:

```java
public void logoutOfWordpress(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String url = wordpressProper.getRestUrl() + "/community-rest/logout";
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = buildHeaderByCookies(cookies);
        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), String.class);
        Object body = exchange.getBody();
    }
```

This is the WordPress logout interface:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'community_rest_logout');

function community_rest_logout() {
    register_rest_route(
        'community-rest',
        '/logout/', 
        array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'logout'
        )
    );
}

function logout() {
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect('http://192.168.100.5:8888/sign_in');
    exit;
}
```

I tried to use Postman to call this logout interface and found that there is
`Set-Cookie`  in the response header. It seems that this is necessary for logout. It seems that I can directly set the  `Max-Age`  of the cookie to
`0`  to achieve the purpose of logout without having to to call the logout interface
.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for user login? Sessions are not started internally in wordpress rest api. You should be able to get the `user_id` if the user is logged in on your logout endpoint. Can you get this?

Generally, nonce is used on rest for unregistered users. You need to send the nonce value in header or parameter. For registered users, you need to authenticate cookies or you can use some rest api authentication plugins.

For a simple hack you can use this at the top of your endpoints:

```
    public function init_cookie() {

        $userID = wp_validate_logged_in_cookie(false);

        if($userID) {
            wp_set_current_user($userID);
        }

    }
```

I would also suggest defining your code in a class or prefixing the names of the functions. The logout function is a very generic name. If this is just for an example, ignore what I said.

Comment: Thank you very much. Currently I am trying such a method to implement SSO. After I log in in wordpress, and then want to log out of wordpress at the same time as I log out in the springboot project, I pass the cookie and then call the custom wordpress logout interface

Comment: If you are using a cookie-based session operation, the code I specified will work. Rest requests do not log in and cookies are not checked by default. You can test a function like get_current_user_id if you wish. Validate the cookie and set the current user at the beginning of your requests to access user information.